# Android TextView respond to html <a> clicks

Tags: android, textview

I have formatted data with commands embedded with  tags. I use the HTML class to populate the TextView. Is there a way to intercept the click on the link and get what was clicked?

```
Html.fromHtml("<a href='CMD:Bahai'>Some Command Link</a>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the WikiNotes example project from Google does exactly that. It uses the Linkify infrastructure with a Provider and MIMIE type to load the right Activity.